# Extracting texts from an element in a HTML page using Jsoup

Tags: html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am extracting texts from the following html element

```
<span class="adr" style="float: none !important;">
     <span class="street-address" style="float: none !important;">18, Jawaharlal Nehru
       Road,
     </span>
     <span  style="float: none !important;" class="estb_addr-HeadingTxt">
       <a style="float: none !important;"   href="http://kolkata.burrp.com/area/park-street" class="locality">&nbsp;Park Street</a></span>
       ,&nbsp;Kolkata<span class="region" style="display: none;">Kolkata
     </span>
</span>
```

For that I wrote the following piece of code:

```
for (Element element : doc.getAllElements()) 
{
        for(Element childelem: element.children())
           {
             if (childelem.hasText() && !childelem.ownText().isEmpty()) 
                {

                     String currText=childelem.ownText();
                     System.out.print(currText+" ");

                  }

            }
         System.out.println("");
 }
```

Ideally the output should be **18, Jawaharlal Nehru Road, Park Street, Kolkata**. But it is giving **18, Jawaharlal Nehru Road, Kolkata** and **Park Street**. I can understand that the output is basically inorder traversal of the DOM tree rooted at outer <span>. But I don't know exactly how to achieve that by Jsoup, where a DOM tree for an element in a HTML page has arbitrary levels of nesting.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use either DOM navigation or CSS-selector syntax to do the task, do not loop through all `Elements`.

```
Element adr = doc.select("span.adr").first().
System.out.println(adr.text());
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. But I am exactly looking for a method to traverse a DOM tree of any level in Depth First Order using Jsoup so that I can extract text from DOM tree of any HTML element. So can you give me any suggestion regarding that.